# How to make a ~/public_html in WHM/cPanel symlink

Tags: linux, symlink, whm

I'm using [Rocketeer](https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer) for deployment on a server that is powered by WHM/cPanel.  I'm having an issue where I'm deploying my app to `~/mysite.com` where Rockteer adds a version of the site in `~/mysite.com/releases/GIT-COMMIT-HASH` and symlinks `~/mysite.com/current` to the latest release.

I'm trying to figure out how to make `~/public_html` for a given user a symlink to this current directory and there seems to be a background process that breaks the symlink every night and recreates the standard `~/public_html/cgi-bin`

Is there a way to work around this or setup a subdomain in cpanel to reference a home directory which is a symlink?

If it were up to me, I wouldn't be using WHM/cPanel...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent `public_html` from being "recreated" each night, the solution is to disable the cgi-bin script alias.  Enabling this enables a nightly process that goes through all domains/subdomains and ensures there's a `cgi-bin` directory.  If not, it'll create it, breaking the `public_html` symlink in the process.

[image: WHM screenshot for cgi-bin script alias]

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it will change that setting for the entire server.  You can actually disable this feature on a per-account basis as well though.

Go to - Home »Account Functions »Modify an Account and uncheck CGI Privilege

This disabled CGI for that account and for most people this isn't an issue.